# Circuit behaves erratically when using a long cable

Tags: power-supply, led

I've got a circuit, it is a dimmer that a friend of mine designed, it is providing energy to 15 meters of 3528 led strips.

I'm using a 12v 5A power supply, and as long as I connect the PS directly to the circuit, it works just fine.

However, when I connect the PS to a cable (1.5 meters long) and then I connect that cable to the circuit, it starts to behave erratically, sometimes it doesn't even start, other times it reach full power and then it shuts down.

I have the circuit details if you need them, just wanted to quickly check out if there is something obvious that I'm not taking into account, since I have barely basic knowledge of electronics. My brother in law (who designed the circuit) is on vacations unfortunately, so I can't consult with him.

Ant help is appreciated.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: *"I have the circuit details if you need them"* - I think that's going to be a prerequisite before you get any useful answers. Also any info on the type of cable you used.

Comment: Yeah I just thought that maybe in this particular case this problem was circuit-independent, but yeah, I will post it as soon as I get it.

Comment: Perhaps it's because long cables acquire static electricity,which is bad for at least some components.

Comment: We tried reducing the amount of leds and even increasing the cable (to a 4meters long cable) and it worked ok. So its related somehow to the consumption too.

Comment: Was the 4m cable **the same type** as the shorter cable ? Not all cables are equal ! It is the diameter of the copper in side the cable that matters (larger = better).

Comment: Yes, same type of course.

Comment: Adding the circuit  details would help a lot.You could get more accurate answers that have a bigger probability to solve your problem.Also,you should pay attention to Roger's comment.Here,on ee stack, you won't get much if your questions are succint and not detailed enough.All in all,you should post the circuit details and bear in mind the detailed question thing.

Comment: Circuit added!.

Comment: Now just changing things randomly might get it going if you have luck.How about testing with the same amount of LEDs.Let's say you add the 1,5 meter wire.It starts malfunctioning.Then you add the 4 meter wire.It should malfunction more.If you make sure every part of the circuit is protected against static electricity discharge,things might get better.Try it!

Answer (score 2):

Circuit + LEDs = fine

Circuit + **cable** + LEDs = **bad**

The logical conclusion is that the cable is causing your problems ! No use looking at the circuits just yet although it is common sense to include all information right from the beginning. The power supply is 12V, 5A and you have a lot of LEDs. So probably a lot of current is flowing.

Let's assume it almost 5 A, for 5 A you need a decent cable for it not to drop too much voltage. What sort of cable are you using ? Do you have a voltmeter which you can use to measure the 12V ath the other end of the cable (when the LEDs are on because only then current flows).

Comment: Actually its like this:

PS -> cable -> circuit -> leds. We tried different cables, and a very powerful PS too (a car one), same problem.

Comment: This still points to the problem I suggested, the circuit is not getting enough voltage due to the cable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the circuit has inadequate input capacitance on the supply. You are adding to the supply output impedance by adding the cable.

A large-ish possibly low-ESR capacitor directly at the circuit input may calm things down. Try at least 1000uF/16V. If there is already one there, increase it significantly (like 5:1).

Where is your brother-in-law that he can't be contacted? There are few places that Internet (perhaps via Iridium sat phone) cannot reach.

Comment: Well is not that we "cant" contact him, more like we don't want to bother him. But thanks for your input on the matter!, it sure helps to shed some light on the matter.

Comment: Circuit added..

Comment: Btw, I did what you proposed, and the circuit burned out instantly :)

Answer (score 0):

Wires have inductance. When the current passing through an inductor changes it produces a voltage. The faster the current changes, and the greater the inductance, the greater the voltage that will be produced.

Your circuit controls the brightness of the LEDs by rapidly switching them on and off, so the current is cycling between 0 and 5A. What effect will this have on your circuit? If the cable is short then its inductance will be low, so any voltage spikes produced probably won't be large enough to cause any harm. A longer cable has more inductance, and therefore produces bigger spikes. At some point the spikes may become large enough to upset the controller.

Here's an [LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) simulation that represents the essentials of your circuit. L1 represents the inductance of the power cable. R6 represents the regulator and its load (MCU).

[image]

With L1 = 0.1uH (representing a short power cable) I got this:-

[image]
You can see a little spike each time the LEDs are turned on, and bigger spike when they turn off. However the maximum and minimum voltages are well within a range that the regulator should be able to handle, so the MCU should still get a stable +5V.

A 1.5m length of 16/2 lamp cable has an inductance of about 1uH. Here's what happened when I put that value into the simulation:-

[image]

Now the voltage spikes are extreme, going up to 24V and down to 1V. The voltage regulator will **not** be able to create a stable +5V from this dirty power!

Finally I added a 47uF low ESR electrolytic capacitor across the supply, in parallel with C1. Now the spikes have completely disappeared! (the remaining square wave is just a small voltage drop caused by power supply and cable resistance):-

[image]